# How do spell/magic immunity and spell/magic resistance work in 5th edition?

Tags: dnd-5e

How do spell/magic resistance and spell/magic immunity work?

Per the *PHB* (p. 197) rules on *damage* resistance:

> If a creature or an object has **resistance** to a damage type, damage of that type is halved against it.

So perhaps spell resistance halves damage from spells. Does spell resistance confer protection against *non-damaging effects*? Does it help with saving throws against charms or web, for example? What about spell immunity?

Per the *MM* (p. 8) rules on vulnerabilities, resistances and immunities:

> Some creatures have vulnerability, resistance, or immunity to certain types of damage... If a creature is immune to a game effect that isn't considered damage or a condition, it has a special trait.

This is a bit sparse.

Aside from the *PHB* rules above on damage resistance, I can't find any reference to immunities or resistances in the indices of the *DMG*, *PHB*, or *MM*.

**EDIT:** Following up on Oblivious Sage's comment below: a number of entries in the *MM* aside from the Tarrasque have "magic resistance" as an ability, notably more powerful devils, demons, angels, etc. These are consistently of the "Advantage on saving throws versus spells and other magical effects."

Comment: Hmmm... I see... I may be making the mistake of carrying previous editions' concepts forward. The Tarrasque has "magic resistance" which is detailed for it (advantage on saving throws against spells and other magical effects), and assumed there was more to it than just for the Tarrasque. TY for the question.

Comment: To be clear, resistance to the magic type is a thing and confers resistance, that is it halves all damage, from magical sources. It is not the same as the Magic Resistance special trait which is always detailed (as mentioned in the answer below).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are no such things in D&D 5e, at least not in a way that would be familiar from experience with previous editions.

**Special Traits** are explained on the following page in the *Monster Manual*. Special Traits are, well, *special*: they are abilities designed specifically for that creature and are defined per-creature in the creature's entry.

Immunities and damage resistance special traits tend to be a straightforward labelled list — for example, the Banshee (p. 23) is immune to a variety of damage types and conditions, and is resistant to another list of damage types. This works similarly to previous editions and won't require an adjustment in how you think about it.

Magic resistance, on the other hand, uses the special trait space to define how it works for that specific creature. An example is the Death Knight (p. 47), which has **Magic Resistance** — it says how it works *for Death Knights* as part of the creature:

> The death knight has advantage on saving throws against spells and other magical effects.

This way of defining special traits with an *ad hoc* rule particular to that creature allows the designers and the DM significant flexibility when creating creatures. It also means that you won't find a general explanation of how magic resistance works outside of a creature's entry, because it's individual to each creature.

Although magic resistance works identically for most (all?) other creatures in the MM that have it, defining it per-creature in 5e means you can't rest comfortable knowing how a monster you're facing works: DMs have the power/authority to alter creatures' special traits, and new creatures (either new-to-your-PC, or in new books) can be made that have a "Magic Resistance" with a different definition.

A good example of this way of using special traits to define traits unique to one creature is the Rakshasa's magic immunity:

> ***Limited Magic Immunity.*** The rakshasa is immune to spells of 6th level or lower unless it wishes to be affected. It has advantage on saving throws against all other spells and magical effects.

It specifies which spells it's immune to and when. You can probably see how the flexibility inherent in this design approach could be used to give a different creature a trait with the exact same "Limited Magic Immunity" name, but with a different description that makes it immune to only Illusion spells, or spells of 3rd level or lower, or spells cast by a cleric, *etcetera*.

Additionally, see how this gives a magic resistance effect identical to the Death Knight's **Magic Resistance**, but without the Rakshasa having a **Magic Resistance** trait! It's just part of the *ad hoc* definition of its **Limited Magic Immunity** trait.

Comment: @Lexible Yep. I've added a bit that shows more how the per-creature definition allows for flexibility that hasn't (yet) been used for Magic Resistance, by looking at the Rakshasa.

Comment: Hmmm... Your 4th paragraph makes me wonder: Are you saying that a monster resistant to *just* fire will take full damage (or 50% on a successful saving throw) from a Fireball because the Fireball is magic? It seems to me that the resistance is a reference to the type of damage that nature or a spell exerts, so that's a resistance against magic too.

Comment: @AlexisWilke No, a Fireball does fire damage, so resistance or immunity to fire damage will work. I'm not sure what in the 4th paragraph would give the impression otherwise. If a fireball were aimed at a Goristro (p. 59), it would get advantage on its save against the fireball *and* get its fire resistance against the half- or full-damage.

Comment: Another important point with the *Limited Magic Immunity*, although it says *Not affected by 6th level or lower spells*, you may still use a spell from a lower level, only you have to cast it using a slot of level 7+ (PHB p. 201 Casting a Spell at a Higher Level).

Comment: how exactly does magic resistances work, I would ask a question but I can't, and I can't find anything about how it works