# Does Magic Resistance work against Turn Undead?

Tags: dnd-5e, undead, saving-throw, resistance

Magic Resistance:

> The flameskull has advantage on saving throws against spells and **other magical effects**.

Turn Undead:

> Each undead that can see or hear you within 30 feet of you must make a **Wisdom saving throw**.

Is *Turn Undead* magical?

Comment: There are now 3 questions that are part of this, and I"m not sure if I've answered correctly. You ask a title question, but then the last two lines of the body are two additional questions. Can you remove those and re-ask them separately?

Comment: related to your other questions: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/55574/how-do-spell-magic-immunity-and-spell-magic-resistance-work-in-5th-edition

Comment: You've cleaned this up, but then asked another question on the site which is basically the question you have in the body? Can you clarify if you'd still like the "Does magic resistance protect against anything that requires a saving throw" for this answer? If so, can you please change the title question to match? If not, can you remove that line and leave this as a Turn Undead/Magic Resistance question?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Yes

Channel Divinity is described on PHB pp 58 (emphasis mine) as:

> At 2nd level, you gain the ability to channel divine energy directly from your deity, using that energy to **fuel magical effects: Turn Undead**...

This clearly marks Channel Divinity as a magical effect, and the Magic Resistance of the Flameskull would be triggered for advantage on the saving throw for Turn Undead.

As for the 2nd question, Magical Resistance is ONLY active against:

> Spells and other magical effects

If something isn't a magical effect or a spell, then Magical Resistance isn't triggered. A more complete answer can be found on [your other question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/99335/how-to-decide-if-an-effect-is-magical-for-magic-resistance).

Comment: This answer is confirmed by the [2019 Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf).

Answer (score 12):

### Channel Divinity is a magical effect.

PHB 58:

> At 2nd level, you gain the ability to channel divine energy directly from your deity, using that energy to fuel magical effects.

Because Turn Undead is a channel divinity effect, that means that it's subject to magic resistance.

I didn't find a definition for "other magical effect," but I'd hazard that it's any effect that is magic but is not explicitly a spell. Magic Resistance doesn't protect against every saving throw; otherwise, it would work on purely mundane things like traps or the Battle Master's maneuvers.