# Can the Purify Food and Water spell fix water impacted/poisoned by the presence of a black dragon?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, dragons, poison, food-and-drink

Can the *purify food and water* spell fix water impacted/poisoned by the presence of a black dragon?

I assume the power of the black dragon would overpower the spell, but I'm not totally sure.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [description of the effects](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/ancient-black-dragon) of a black dragon on the area specifies

> Water **sources** within 1 mile of the lair are supernaturally fouled. Enemies of the dragon that drink such water regurgitate it within minutes.

Not all water is fouled, just the *sources* of water.  Therefore drinkable water can certainly exist in the radius of a black dragon.  In the absence of a rule specifying otherwise, *purify food and drink* should work as normal and purify any water it is cast on.

Comment: Purify works on nonmagical water only. Is supernaturally fouled water nonmagical?

Comment: @NautArch the rules don't make a distinction between supernatural and natural, and since this effect is not magical (since it doesn't say it's magical) it's a perfectly normal effect.

Comment: @NautArch "Purify works on nonmagical water only." and water around the liar is not fouled magically, but supernaturally.  According to [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/99336/10642) there is no reason to treat this effect as magical

Comment: If you want the dragon's poison to have impact, add an arcana/religion roll along with the spellcasting to check if the spellcaster is 'powerful' enough to dispell the foulness.
Make the DC pretty low though, as the spell itslef already expends a spellslot.