# Do any enemies have Turn Resistance?

Tags: dnd-5e

In DnD 5e, a few enemies have Turn Immunity, which gives them immunity to the class feature, Turn Undead. But, in 5e, does Turn Resistance exist?

I know it exists in 3.5e, but I can not find anything saying it does or does not exist in 5e.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are several examples of such.

The Death Knight grants itself and nearby undead advantage against effects that would turn undead, though the ability is called Marshal Undead, not Turn Resistance.

The demilich has as a lair feature a similar ability.

Ghasts have Turning Defiance, which does the same.

Liches, as already mentioned, straight up have Turn Resistance.

Mummy lords have a similar lair feature to demiliches.

There are probably more, but overall, resistance to turning isn't as uncommon as you might think.

As an extra note, [Magic Resistance also applies](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/99316/does-magic-resistance-work-against-turn-undead), thanks to @András for pointing that out.

Comment: I see. I am working on a heroic item for a cleric in my adventure, and I am making an ability that is not turn undead but counts as it when enemies are checking for resistances and immunities.

Comment: You should add that [_Magic Resistance_ works against turning](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/99316/does-magic-resistance-work-against-turn-undead), so even more undead has resistance than it seems

Comment: @András Good catch, I'll add it now.

Answer (score 7):

It does exist, though the only example in the MM is the lich (p. 202):

> Turn Resistance. The lich has advantage on saving throws against any
>   effect that turns undead.

The Alhoon in Volo's guide (p. 172) also has this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly of relevance: *Tales From The Yawning Portal* includes an "Amulet of Protection From Turning" in one adventure. ("...you have advantage on saving throws against effects that turn undead. If you fail a saving throw against such an effect, you can choose to suceed again... three times... recharge daily at dawn.")