# How do curses work with magic resistance?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic, resistance

For instance, when casting the [Bestow Curse](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/bestow-curse) spell on a creature with magic resistance it would have advantage on making the wisdom save. However what happens after it fails the save? Does it have advantage on all subsequent saves or do curses operate differently?

For an example curse I usually choose:

> While Cursed, the target must make a Wisdom saving throw at the start of each of its turns. If it fails, it wastes its action that turn doing nothing.

Comment: Related (possible duplicate): "[How to decide if an effect is magical for Magic Resistance?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/99335)"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### The creature with Magic Resistance would have advantage on all subsequent saves against spells and other magical effects.

Taking from this [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/99319/53298) to a similar question, if a creature has to make a save due to a spell, or magical effect, it would have advantage on that save.

> **Magic Resistance**. The {creature} has advantage on saving throws
>   against spells and other magical effects. (MM, standard phrasing for magic resistance in the stat blocks)

From the specific example you gave with Bestow Curse, this would also apply to all subsequent saves if it fails. The curse bestowed on the creature by Bestow Curse is magical, as per this [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/99336/53298), because it is a spell. Since the curse is magical, they are continuously making a save against the magical effect of the curse to resist its effects. This means they would have advantage on the save against the curse's effects.

None of the other suggested Bestow Curse examples require additional saving throws, and would probably be better to use against a creature with Magical Resistance.